# cannot find "language settings" in sharepoint server 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, multilingual

i want to use multilanguage support in sharepoint ,

so after installing language pack and reconfiguring sharepoint

i couldn't find "language settings" under site administration in site settings

any ideas ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you have installed the language pack, you should be able to change it on the site settings for each site/site collection.

On top of that, the user can change the language on a per-user basis.